# How to exit feature's navigation graph?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a feature as a module which consist of 3 fragments.
After User navigates to the 3'd fragment, there is a computation, when computation succeeds -> User should be navigated to the Home screen which is in the parent nav graph.

I've tried a lot of approaches, but nothing seem to work correctly, is there a way to finish current navigation graph and return to the parent graph?

Things I've tried:
Navigation to the home with a help of deeplink. Not a bad option, but it messes with backStack, and it is not user friendly in case feature will be exposed to different clients.

Navigating to the start destination with cleaning of the backstack and after navigateUp. Better option than the first, but still...

Comment: So the home screen is already on that back stack and you just want to pop everything in your graph off the back stack? That sounds like exactly what `popBackStack()` is for. Can you add your "Before" back stack and you expected "After" back stack?

Comment: Yes, of course, 
before:
A(home) -> B -> C -> D
after: 
A(home)

Basically, I need to remove B, C, D after some processing in D and return to A with cleared backstack

Comment: So what happens when you use `navController.popBackStack()` and you pass it B (and the inclusive = true flag)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sorry for long response. 
Yes, it works, and it works as expected, but there is one strange behaviour, maybe it's because of the messed up project, that I'm working on. But when I'm returning to the A screen, it looks like, the fragment is messed up, and it doesn't update the UI at all. 
All of the observers are following view lifecycle, also all of the elements have new hashcodes, not the old ones, and everything seems legit. Maybe it will work okay on a sandbox project, need to test. But generally thanks.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Can you help me with other flow. Everything is the same, for the one exception, now I need to navigate from A(home) screen, to the D screen of feature module, pass there a bundle for processing and after processing is done I need to return back to the A(home).
I've tried with actions, but it look like it needs to replace graph and after that navigate to. Deep link is also not suitable, because we can't pass bundle with it.